# Thread Synchronization in Java(Android) Legacy Code

Tags: java, android

I have a legacy application to maintain and there is some code written like

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
   ...(some code)

 Class cls = MyApplication.class;
        __monitor_enter(cls);

   ...(some code)

__monitor_exit(cls);

 ...(some code)
}
```

to my best of knowledge some sort of thread synchronization is going on here, but [**as explained here**](http://www.android-decompiler.com/apidoc/jeb/api/ast/Monitor.html)

> This AST element represents a "monitor" statement. It can be one of two types:

```
__monitor_enter(lock)
__monitor_exit(lock)
```

> Such statements are not legal Java constructs. Combined with
>   try-finally blocks, they are used to represent very high-level
>   constructs known as synchronized blocks.
>
> Currently, monitors statements are read-only elements and cannot be
>   user-created.

at some places the `__monitor_enter` is giving error and in some places its not, what probably could be the reason, if somebody understand the style of code please tell what is the purpose of such statement and how i can improve it.

Edit:

the error is

> The method __monitor_exit(Object) is undefined for the type MyApplication

and

> The method __monitor_enter(Object) is undefined for the type MyApplication

Regards.

Comment: What's the error ? As for your last question you can remove the monitors and wrap the code in synchronization block instead.

Comment: Is this what the class actually looks like? I mean, that's not even valid Java with arbitrary code in the class definition like that.

Comment: @JanVandenbosch the class definition was not important in context of the question to i left out the class details for brevity ...

Comment: @alfasin can you provide an example of how can i wrap it in the synchronization block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a synchronization block:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
   ...(some code)

   synchronized (MyApplication.class) {    
      ...(some code)    
   }

   ...(some code)
}
```

As for the monitor, it seems that it can except as a locking object only a specific type of class/object. Check an occurrence where it compiles fine and see which type of object is used there.

Comment: just one question, will this synchronization block take care of unlocking/exit, like its done in the erroneous code `__monitor_exit(lock) `

Comment: Yes, it will allow only one thread (at a time) to enter the block.